# How can I determine the page count of djvu documents from the CLI?

Tags: djvu

Finding the page count of a PDF document from the CLI is as simple as:

```
pdfinfo file.pdf | grep ^Pages:
```

How can the same be performed with a djvu file? Without converting it to a pdf and then deleting the pdf file after checking the number of pages, please.

Answer (score 6):

```
djvused -e n file.djvu
```

(from http://djvu.sourceforge.net/, `djvulibre-bin` package on Debian and derivatives).